# How to convert resultset value into integer format in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

This query selects random client_id value from the table. And i need that value in another query.

```
String s= "SELECT client_id FROM clients OFFSET random()*(select count(*) from clients) LIMIT 1";
d=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = d.executeQuery(s);
```

UPDATE: I tried to cast like this

```
int  val =  ((Number) rs1).intValue();
```

sql error shows like this

```
rg.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gResultSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I want to use the value of result set in my another query

```
insert  into invheader(invdate,client_id,amount,tax,total,closed,ship_via,note)
values(
to_date('"+indate+"', 'DD-mon-YYYY'),
'"+rs1+"',   //<<---- i need to pass the value of result set in integer format
'"+amont+"',
'"+tx+"',
'"+tot+"',
'"+closd+"',
'"+shipvia+"',
'"+not+"')";
```

UPDATE: I am passing value from servlet to postgresdb

Comment: while(rs1.next()){int clientID =rs1.getInt("client_id");} shall give you the id

Comment: Eep. Please see http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Don't do that. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Apart from protecting your application from SQL injection it also makes dealing with different data types *much* easier (dates, Strings that include `'`, numbers, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the round trip and do it all in SQL

```
with client_id as (
    select client_id
    from clients
    offset random() * (select count(*) from clients)
    limit 1
)
insert into invheader (
    invdate, client_id, amount, tax, total, closed, ship_via, note
) values (
to_date('"+indate+"', 'DD-mon-YYYY'),
(select client_id from client_id), //<<---- i need to pass the value of result set in integer format
'"+amont+"',
'"+tx+"',
'"+tot+"',
'"+closd+"',
'"+shipvia+"',
'"+not+"')";
```

And be very aware of SQL injection:

[https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)